# Data loader api hit

Tags: data-loader

Is their any formula which can tell us that how many hits does data loader makes while importing or exporting data from salesforce .

or

Can we know the average api hits per number of records which data loader makes while exporting or importing data from Salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How are API calls consumed by Data Loader?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205658)

> The number of batches submitted for a data manipulation operation
>   depends on the number of records and batch size selected. The total
>   number of records in your file divided by the batch size selected
>   equals the number of batches. **Each batch consumes one API call.**
>
> The default batch size in Data Loader is 200 or if you select the
>   "Enable Bulk API" setting the default batch size is 2,000.

For example, with an API request limit of 15,000 and a batch size of 200 it would be possible to perform operations on (15,000 X 200) or 3,000,000 records per 24 hours.

If using the "Enable Bulk API" option with Data Loader and a batch size of 2,000 it would be possible to perform operations on (15,000 X 2,000) or 30,000,000 records per 24 hours.